# How to get my custom validation workign with 2 parameters (Asp.net mvc 3)

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a ViewModel that holds Date, Hour and minute as a string, each of these have a textbox for entering values into them, what I then want is a custom validator that ensures that if a value is entered into one of the fields then the rest have to be filled out as well, otherwise they can be empty, its all or nothing!

I have made a little test project here, but its not workign the way it should, I have followed http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2 but I think my issues are clientside, as I cant see any value on the Params if I do a breakpoint in chrome.

The View:

```
@model validationproject.Models.DateTimeViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ViewPage1";
}

<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/Validators.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<h2>ViewPage1</h2>
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("CreateDateTime", "Home", new {}, new AjaxOptions {HttpMethod = "Post"}))
{
    <span>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Date, new {@Id = "date"}) 

    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Hour, new {@Id = "hour"})

    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Minute, new {@Id = "minute"})

    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Date)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Hour)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Minute)
    </span>
}
```

JQuery validator file

```
$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add(
            'fulldaterequired',
            ['part1', 'part2'],
            function (options) {
                options.rules['fulldaterequiredcheck'] = options.params;
                options.messages['fulldaterequiredcheck'] = options.message;
            }
        );

$.validator.addMethod(
        'fulldaterequiredcheck',
        function (value, element, params) {

            if (!value && (params['otherproperty1'] || params['otherproperty2'])) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    );
```

My Viewmodel

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace validationproject.Models
{
    public class DateTimeViewModel  
    {
        [Display(Name = "Date")]
        [FullDateRequired(("Hour"), ("Minute"))]
        public string Date { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Hour")]
        [FullDateRequired(("Minute"), ("Date"))]
        public string Hour { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Minute")]
        [FullDateRequired(("Hour"), ("Date"))]
        public string Minute { get; set; }
    }

    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
    public sealed class FullDateRequired : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
    {
        private const string DefaultErrorMessage = "{0} is required.";
        public string OtherProperty1 { get; private set; }
        public string OtherProperty2 { get; private set; }
        public FullDateRequired(string otherProperty1, string otherProperty2)
            : base(DefaultErrorMessage)
        {
            OtherProperty1 = otherProperty1;
            OtherProperty2 = otherProperty2;
        }
        public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
        {
            return string.Format(ErrorMessageString, name);
        }
        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            var otherProperty1 = validationContext.ObjectInstance.GetType().GetProperty(OtherProperty1);
            var otherProperty2 = validationContext.ObjectInstance.GetType().GetProperty(OtherProperty2);
            var otherProperty1Value = string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)otherProperty1.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null));
            var otherProperty2Value = string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)otherProperty2.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null));

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)value) && (!otherProperty1Value || !otherProperty2Value))
            {
                return new ValidationResult(FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName));
            }
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
        public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
        {
            var clientValidationRule = new ModelClientValidationRule()
            {
                ErrorMessage = FormatErrorMessage(metadata.GetDisplayName()),
                ValidationType = "fulldaterequired"
            };
            clientValidationRule.ValidationParameters.Add("otherproperty1", OtherProperty1);
            clientValidationRule.ValidationParameters.Add("otherproperty2", OtherProperty2);
            return new[] { clientValidationRule };
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your javascript contains 'part1' and 'part2' which should be 'otherproperty1' and 'otherproperty2' as defined in your viewmodel. The correct script should be:

```
$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add(
        'fulldaterequired',
        ['otherproperty1', 'otherproperty2'],
        function (options) {
            options.rules['fulldaterequiredcheck'] = options.params;
            options.messages['fulldaterequiredcheck'] = options.message;
        }
    );

        $.validator.addMethod(
    'fulldaterequiredcheck',
    function (value, element, params) {
        if (value == '' && ($('#' + params['otherproperty1']).val() != '' || $('#' + params['otherproperty2']).val() != '')) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
);
```

Add this to your view (inside the form) to show errormessages when you press the submit button:

```
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Date)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Hour)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Minute)

    <input type="submit" />
```

Comment: Changed some code now, but if I type anything in one of my 3 textboxes it adds the class "Valid" to those, but nothing is added to the one that should fail? So those without text in them (while other textfields have text should fail)

Comment: Edited the answer, changed the logic of the fulldaterequiredcheck, should work now

Comment: Edited again, made a mistake.

Comment: Still dont give me any error messages at any point http://www.gratisimage.dk/graphic/images/2011/August/21/AD64_4E511CF7.jpg the middle field should not validate correctly

Comment: Edited the answer, added validationmessages

Comment: Hmm, why isnt it validated when the user type? It gives me the error message when I click submit. Also it complains that not typing in any of them is an error (so atm it just works as a [Required] attritute.

Comment: That's how jquery validate works, it validates after submit. After a submit it does trigger when a single input is changed.

Comment: But do you know why it says that its wrong if all fields are empty? (Then it should also be valid)

Comment: Did you use the latest version of my answer? I made a mistake at first, but now it should work correctly. In my solution if you click the button when no values are entered the form is valid.

Comment: I get "Date is required. Hour is required. Minute is required." if I dont enter anythign I yes I have your latest Jquery script :/

Comment: If I do alert('#' + params['otherproperty1']);
        alert('#' + params['otherproperty2']); inside the function then they both just return something like "#Hour" and "#Minute" etc

Comment: You should use alert($('#' + params['otherproperty1']).val()) to see the value. The id's in your view should be Date, Hour and Minute, not date, hour and minute, I think that's causing the error.

Comment: It was the IDs but not sure I like that :/ then in my real project where I have 3 DateViewModels I have to have 3 with Id Hour, Minute and Date, that might confuse it again :S

Comment: Well you got ik working now, I'm sure you'll be able to tweak it further in something you like. Good luck!